# How can you add additional logic to type resolution at runtime?

Tags: .net, clr, types

Is there a generic way, without creating and managing your own CLR host, to take over locating and loading a type if that type is not found?

**The following is just an example.  In your rush to be the first answer, don't suggest the new add-in framework or the MEF as a solution to my question.**

An example would be a sample with add-ins.  Your app reads a file in that lists the types to use for a particular function. The app attempts to instantiate those types.  If they aren't already currently loaded in the appdomain, the method fails.  I'm looking for an event I can handle or a component I can provide my own implementation for that will allow me to gracefully handle these situations and provide additional logic for loading these assemblies.

---

As far as I can tell (unless somebody has an example that works) none of the so-far mentioned AppDomain events fire when a type isn't found.

---

Wait, apparently [this is working](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.typeresolve.aspx)!  Not sure what I did wrong before, but this event fires good and well.

Comment: Could you provide us some code sample that isn't working for you? What of this sample (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.typeresolve.aspx) won't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are events on the [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain_events.aspx) that you can use.

You would want [TypeResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.typeresolve.aspx) event, and possibly the [AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event.

Also, you can read more about how the [.net runtime resolves assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx), so it's possible you could define this information in the probing section.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that possible just by using AppDomain events?